# How can I solve an error with Carthage and Swift version?

Tags: swift, carthage

I get an error when doing `carthage update --plaform ios`

Here is the cartfile:

```
github "Alamofire/Alamofire" ~> 4.4
github "ReactiveX/RxSwift" ~>  4.3.1
github "RxSwiftCommunity/RxAlamofire" ~> 4.4.0
github "onevcat/Kingfisher" ~> 3.0
github "patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar" ~> 7.0
github "stripe/stripe-ios"
```

And the Log error:

> error: SWIFT_VERSION '5.0' is unsupported, supported versions are: 3.0, 4.0, 4.2. (in target 'RxAlamofire iOS')

My project use Swift 4.2 and I check on the RxAlamofire github project the 4.4.0 and it's for Swift 4.2.

Does any one have the same issue and know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove RXAlamofire version and try again

```
github "Alamofire/Alamofire" ~> 4.4
github "ReactiveX/RxSwift" ~>  4.3.1
github "RxSwiftCommunity/RxAlamofire"
github "onevcat/Kingfisher" ~> 3.0
github "patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar" ~> 7.0
github "stripe/stripe-ios"
```

You can also remove the whole first line  `github "Alamofire/Alamofire" ~> 4.4` since Alamofire is the dependency of RXAlamofire and will be downloaded automatically.

Personal experience : I usually don't specify a specific version unless I have a reason for that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got an other answer for github, tried and it works. here is the link : https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxAlamofire/issues/144

Comment: @apparence I can’t tell you’re welcome since you find your answer somewhere else , but happy that your problem is solved,good luck.